# mongoose query for top 5 viewed projects (sorted) using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mongodb, mongoose

i have a site with multiple projects. and each project has a different view count. 
What i want to do is **to retrieve an array of the top 5 viewed projects in this order `[max, max-1, max-2, max-3, max-4].`**

here's the schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// defines the database schema for this object
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  projectName : String,
  authorName : String,
  viewCount : Number

   comment : [{
      id : String,                                  
      authorName : String,
      authorEmailAddress : { type : String, index : true }  
    }]
  });
```

`})`

```
// Sets the schema for model
var ProjectModel = mongoose.model('Project', schema);

// Create a project
exports.create = function (projectJSON) {

  var project = new ProjectModel({

    projectName : projectJSON.projectName ,
    authorName : projectJSON.authorName,    
    viewCount :  projectJSON.viewCount,    

    comment : [{
      id : projectJSON.comments.id,                                         
      authorName : projectJSON.comments.authorName,                         
      authorEmailAddress : projectJSON.authorEmailAddress
    });

  project.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("success");
    }
  });


}
```

Below is my attempt to retrieve an array of the top 5 viewed articles in this order `[max, max-1, max-2, max-3, max-4]`. Bearing in mind that articles view rank change in real time.

`// because i am familiar with SQL, i start with a SQL query and convert it later to mongoose`

SQL version:

`SELECT MAX(viewCount) FROM project where projectName=1   --this only give the MAX when i want the top 5`

mongoose version:

```
exports.getTopViewedProject = function(rank, callback)
   ProjectModel.findOne({ projectName: 1 }).sort(viewCount, -1).run( 
       function(err, viewCOunt) {
         var max = viewCount;
    });
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your schema definition.  Where's the `article` field that's in your `findOne` call

Comment: sorry about that, i edited it using the previous question schema

Comment: Thanks.  You talk about wanting the top 5 articles but then you're querying for the max `viewCount`.  Which one do you need help with?

Comment: i would like the top 5 projects please. i showed my work for the max `viewCount` to show at least i'm trying to think of a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the top 5 articles for project 'name' by `viewCount`:

```
ProjectModel.find({projectName: 'name'}).sort({viewCount: -1}).limit(5).exec( 
    function(err, projects) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: should it be `function(err, project)` because `project` was defined as `var project = new ProjectModel(...)`

Comment: @bouncingHippo It's just a parameter name so it can be anything; I was just going off your description of the problem.  Your schema is a little confusing because your `Projects` schema seems to contain articles, not projects.

Comment: its my first time designing schema. Basically, its a website with many projects. A user can create a project. Each project can be viewed by many users. So what i was trying to do is to find the top 5 most viewed project. I'll be really grateful if you can give feedback on my schema too. thanks!!

Comment: @bouncingHippo That part makes sense, but then why are you filtering on `projectName` in your query?  Can there be more than one document in `Projects` with the same `projectName`?

Comment: im still new to the syntax, what if i dont do filtering on `projectName` and there are indeed more than 1 document in `ProjectModel` with the same `projectName`...how will the function be modified?

Comment: @bouncingHippo These are some pretty fundamental concepts.  I think you should consider stepping back from your coding a bit and take some time to learn more about MongoDB.

Comment: if i were to filter on `project.id` which is unique instead of the `projectName` would make more sense

Comment: @bouncingHippo Not if you're also sorting to find the most viewed projects.